# NHibernate Table Per Class loading - wrong type

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a mapping issue with the table-per-class hierarchy in Fluent/NHibernate.  When retrieving the records from the database, I keep getting an error (the Wrong type exception)

Object with id: 2445763 was not of the specified subclass: ClassA (loading object was of wrong class [ClassB])  (record 2445763 does have the value "2" in the Type column)

In my domain, I have EntryBase, ClassA and ClassB.  The classes are defined as

```
public abstract class EntryBase 
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string CommonProperty1 {get;set;}
    *... (lots of other common properties)*
    public virtual string CommonPropertyN {get;set;}
}

public class ClassA : EntryBase 
{
    public virutal string ClassAOnlyProperty {get;set;}
}

public class ClassB : EntryBase 
{
    public virutal string ClassBOnlyProperty {get;set;}
    public virutal int ClassBOnlyOtherProperty {get;set;}
}
```

The mappings are:

```
public class EntryBaseMap : ClassMap<EntryBase>
{
    public EntryBaseMap()
    {
        Table("MySingleTable");
        Id(x => x.Id, "RecordId").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.CommonProperty1, "Field1Name");
        ...
        Map(x => x.CommonPropertyN, "FieldNName");
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<string>("Type");
    }
}

public class ClassAMap : SubclassMap<ClassA>
{   
    public ClassAMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("1");
        Map(x => x.ClassAOnlyProperty);
    }
}

public class ClassBMap : SubclassMap<ClassB>
{   
    public ClassBMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("2");
        Map(x => x.ClassBOnlyProperty);
        Map(x => x.ClassBOnlyOtherProperty);
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be amiss?  I've correctly been able to store records of Class B, but when I retrieve them, it's attempting to load them as Class A.  Is it a mapping problem?

Comment: What is the query that yields this exception?

Comment: Ok, I think I'm actually fighting this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641124/fluent-nhibernate-table-per-class-hierarchy-need-to-use-where instead.

Comment: I have another class that has a List<ClassA> and a List<ClassB> as collections on it.  Loading that class is causing this exception to occur.

Comment: Then, yes, in those mappings you need to add a `Where` clause. Something like `.Where("Type = '1'")` and `.Where("Type = '2'")`

Comment: Yeah, that got it.  Throw that in as an answer, I'll accept!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, if you have collection properties meant to represent a single subclass, you need to add a where clause in the mapping:

```
.Where("Type = '1'")
```

`Type` is your discriminator column and `1` is the discriminator value that matches the type you're trying to load.

Comment: Where do you put the `where(type=1)` ?

Comment: @Alex On the Fluent NHibernate mapping. `Map(x => x.MyProperty).Where("type=1");`